# exec: “gcc”: executable file not found in %PATH% when trying go build

Tags: go, path, windows-10, cgo

I am running `go` on a relatively restricted system under Windows 10.

In my go program, there is some CGO code so I must have a GCC compiler to use it.

For some reason, here, it is impossible to install typical systems such as `Cygwin` or `MSYS`, which would make the task easier.

Nonetheless, I managed to install the Ubuntu subsystem.

This is great, it means that after the following command:

```
doskey gcc=Ubuntu run gcc
```

when I try to execute  `gcc` on Windows I obtain:

```
C:\PathToFolder\>gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

However, when I try to then, compile my Go code, I have:

```
C:\PathToFolder\>go run Main.go
# _/C_/PathToFolder/Package/File
exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Is there any way to force Windows to use my own `gcc command` through the Ubuntu subsystem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: you can run your `go` program in `WSL` itself or is there a problem?

Comment: @GauravDhiman there is a problem. I am not even sure that the gcc produced by the WSL will be compliant with the rest of the app... But still, looking for solution :/

Comment: You can try using prebuilt binary of MinGW for windows.